# How to select schema/table/column in Sequel using the shortcut syntax?

Tags: ruby, sequel

In Sequel, one can use `:a__b` to generate SQL such as `"a"."b"`. This syntax doesn't work though when we want a fully qualified statement to get to a column, such as:

```
> Sequel.version
=> "4.25.0"
> puts RDB[:store__albums].select(:store__albums__title___album_title).sql
SELECT "store"."albums__title" AS "album_title" FROM "store"."albums"
# I expected:
# SELECT "store"."albums"."title" AS "album_title" FROM "albums"."title"
```

I know I can use `Sequel.lit` to generate the correct value, but I expected the fluent syntax to support this. Does Sequel support this out of the box?

I am using the PostgreSQL driver.

Comment: As you can probably tell from me writing comments and then deleting them, I am greatly confused by your question. If `x` is your table and `c` is your column, what are `a` and `b`? Are you trying to do `schema.table.column AS alias` or something else? Is this some Pg functionality I'm not familiar with? Is `a.b.c` some embedded structure in a column?

Comment: @mwp You're right the example didn't really make sense. I rewrote it so it does now.

Comment: `store` is your schema, `albums` is your table, `title` is your column?

Comment: @mwp, yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Jeremy Evans, Sequel does not support the [fluent syntax to 3 levels deep](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sequel-talk/7W4TJf85qOk).

Instead, the solution is to use lower-level methods to do so:

```
puts RDB[:store__albums].
  select(Sequel.qualify(:store, :albums__title).
           as(:album_title)).sql
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close. I think. :-)

```
RDB[:store__albums].select(:title___album_title)
```

Should get you the following SQL:

```
SELECT "title" AS "album_title" FROM "store"."albums"
```

Is that not acceptable?

Comment: The code I have currently is `JOIN`ing tables together. I really *must* be able to put the triplet in the query: `join(:x, :a__b__c => :r__x__y)`. [Jeremy replied on the Sequel mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sequel-talk/7W4TJf85qOk) and said I'd have to use `Sequel.qualify` to do what I want.